# Exaggerating a sample to represent the whole

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when you exaggerate a limited sample to give a fact or opinion about a whole population, especially for the purposes of boasting.

e.g. 
"All French wine is delicious!", said M Pompidou even though he had tasted only a few French wines.

What is he doing here, beyond just exaggerating? Would this be *hyperbole*?

Answer (score 1):

Overgeneralize / overgeneralization